# Discord Rewrite, Event Loop is not callable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to write a bot in rw, when I start the bot I get the following error "TypeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object is not callable"

I've tried @tasks.loop and @bot.loop neither work and I don't know what else to do.

```
status = cycle(['Test1', 'Test2'])

@bot.loop(seconds=15)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `tasks` extension for that. Valid decorator would be `@tasks.loop(seconds=15.0)`.

You can read more on it here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/.

Comment: Thanks for this! I forgot to import tasks.